# C# Cast Object in generic list

Tags: c#, reflection, casting, generic-list, typeof

I have an object with properties. Some properties are generic list. For example `IList<IArticle>` or `IList<IProduct>` and so on.

I iterate over all properties in the object with `myObject.GetType().GetProperties()` and search for properties which are from type IList.

I can identify the IList-properties and would like to iterate over the list. But there is my problem. I can't cast the listProperty (which is of type object) into generic list. The problem is that the properties are different generic types. To cast into IList will work only for the property which are from type `IList<IArticle>`, but not for the rest like `IList<IProdukt>`...

Cast into `IList<object>` is always null.

Here is a example code:

```
foreach (var myProperty in myObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    //get generic property (type IList)
    if (myProperty.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
    {
        PropertyInfo propInfo = myObject.GetType().GetProperty(myProperty.Name);
        Type propType = myObject.GetType().GetProperty(myProperty.Name).PropertyType;
        var listProperty = propInfo.GetValue(myProperty);

        foreach (var test in (listProperty as IList<???>))
        {
            //Do some magic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<T>` implements `IList`, so just cast to an `IList`.  You can't cast to a generic here because each generic type is different, as you pointed out.  What are you trying to accomplish through reflection?  Why do you want to loop over each of the properties?  You lose the support of the type system doing that.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the relationship between `IArticle` and `IProdukt`?

Comment: thanks, im such a ..., I forgot to include the System.Collections namespace

Comment: Can you show the basic definition of the class, `IArticle` and `IProdukt`?

Comment: How about splitting up the `foreach()` into two loops, one for `List<IArtcle>` and one for `List<IProdukt>`. Otherwise you need to find the commonality between the two in order to handle them in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to iterate over the list. Just cast to `IEnumerable`.
Don't forget to include `using System.Collections;`.

```
foreach (var myProperty in myObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    //get generic property (type IList)
    if (myProperty.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
    {
        var listProperty = myProperty.GetValue(myObject) as IEnumerable;

        foreach (var test in listProperty)
        {
            //Do some magic
        }
    }
}
```